# How do you read/write PDM Vault properties (such as Revision) from a Solidworks CAD API?

Tags: solidworks

I know SOLIDWORKS will unload and reload the document when file is checked-out an checked-in. I have tried this event: `DPartDocEvents_FileReloadNotifyEventHandler` but this event is firing confusingly (i-e it is only firing for `SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.PartDoc` and not for `SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.AssemblyDoc`) and sometimes this event totally not fired on checked-out an checked-in.

I know, we need a PDM vault database access for this but the SW add-in I created will be deployed to dozens of clients, so I don't think it would be good to ask credentials for their vault and the clients will not appreciate.

Other than that, I wanted to know if there is any other solution we can implement without creating PDM add-in which will communicate with my CAD add-in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a way to read PDM values via SOLIDWORKS COM API directly unless properties you're trying to read/write are mapped to custom properties of the particular file, that is opened in SOLIDWORKS.
If that's the case - you can try to change that property value and it'll be mapped back to the file Data Card so that PDM then will realize that there was some change if that's what you want.